# Categorical Calendar Plot

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization

Has anyone used [calmap's](https://pypi.org/project/calmap/) calendar plot for categorical data? What's the best way to alter the colorbar to show the categorical variables as key for every color?

Comment: My solution to this was to use the existing functionality, but create a distinct number based mapping for each individual category, and then use the "summer" color mapping.